# Comprobar constantemente si existe una SESSION abierta - PHP

Tags: php, session

Me acabo de tomar con un glitch en mi programación.
El problema se causa cuando se abren 2 pestañas de la misma sesión, y se cierra sesión en una de estas.
La que fue cerrada, elimina las variables de sesión, y envía al login a que se inicie una nueva.
Pero la pestaña que queda, mantiene la sesión mientras está abierta, y se puede ejecutar acciones mientras permanezca.
El modo en el que yo estoy revisando si la SESSION existe es el sgte:

```
//Compruebo si existe alguna SESSION, sino la inicia
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
//Si existe una session iniciada, los envía a mi pagina
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
    header("location: miPagina.php");
    exit;
}
//Si no existe una SESSION iniciada, los manda al login
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] === false) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

Pero estas validaciones son solo con respuesta del servidor, por lo que por eso permanece la pestaña a pesar de que en otro lado se haya cerrado y destruido las sesiones.

Comment: En cada pestaña abierta debe haber consultas periódicas al servidor, podría ser con  AJAX, pero no es tan recomendable por consumo de recursos. Dependiendo del proyecto y características del servidor, podrías usar [Websockets](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.swoole-websocket-server.php) para mantener abierta la comunicación entre cliente / servidor.

Answer (score 1):

La opción no recomendada, con AJAX podría ser muy sencilla, tratando de no consumir demasiados recursos, creando un script PHP que solo verifique si hay sesión o no:

ajax-session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//Si existe una session iniciada, devuelve 1
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
    die(1);
}
// De lo contrario, devuelve cero
die(0);
```

En Javascript ejecutas una petición cada 3 segundos para verificar la sesión, pero solo debe estar donde se requiera una sesión activa, no debe aparecer en la página de inicio de sesión:

```
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
    // Ejecutar cada 3 segundos
    setInterval(ajaxSession, 3000);
});

function ajaxSession() {
    fetch('ajax-session.php')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            if(data != 1) {
                // No hay sesión activa, redirigir a inicio de sesión
                window.location.href = 'login.php';
            }
        }).catch(e => {
            // Hubo error verificando la sesión, revisa la consola para corregir
            console.log(e.message);
        });
}
```

Aparte de esto, de acuerdo a lo que mencionas:

> Pero la pestaña que queda, mantiene la sesión mientras está abierta, y **se puede ejecutar acciones mientras permanezca**.

Me parece que tienes un serio problema de validación al realizar esas acciones, no deberías permitirlas si ya se cerró la sesión, es decir, el usuario podría intentar esas acciones, pero debe recibir mensaje de error por no tener sesión activa en lugar de poder ejecutarlas.

Comment: Respecto a la segundo, puedo implementar una sencilla validación extra creo, probaré y veré que sucede.